# Какую форму при выводе данных использовать?

Tags: html, jstl

При выводе информации о моем студенте из базы данных я использую тег form , но я не знаю как мне его вывести просто в ячейку , не использую теги по типу input , textarea и т.д . По другому почему то не получается. Выглядит это сейчас вот так : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а мне надо чтобы эта информация была просто в ячейке , также прилагаю свой код вывода :

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: small; line-height: 25px; border-color: #D1EEEE">

  <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
    <th width="100px">Name</th>
    <th width="230px">Surname</th>
    <th width="270px">Group</th>
    <th width="220px">Date of enrollment</th>
  </tr>

  <form:form action="studentProgress" modelAttribute="student">

    <form:hidden path="id" />
    <tr valign="bottom">

      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <form:form path="name" />
      </td>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <form:input path="surname" />
      </td>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <form:select path="group" />
      </td>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <form:textarea path="date" />
      </td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </form:form>


</table>
```

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь в решении данной задачи !

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено , необходимо было поместить мои данные между тегами

и информация начала выводиться корректно :

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: small; line-height: 25px; border-color: #D1EEEE">

  <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
    <th width="100px">Name</th>
    <th width="230px">Surname</th>
    <th width="270px">Group</th>
    <th width="220px">Date of enrollment</th>
  </tr>

  <form:form action="studentProgress" modelAttribute="student">

    <form:hidden path="id" />
    <tr valign="bottom">

      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <p>${student.name}</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <p>${student.surname}</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <p>${student.group}</p>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">
        <p>${student.date}</p>
      </td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </form:form>


</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]